# Jmeter plugin w/ SonarQube

Tags: jmeter, sonarqube

I am trying to setup Sonarqube to collect JMeter results. Being redirected to: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-jmeter - which has jmeter plugin, jmeter report server and client - but no documentation.

Would appreciate any direction in setting up:
1. Jmeter report server to collect execution results
2. Sonarqube with jmeter plugin
3. Sonarqube setup with jmeter-report-server

Comment: See the following thread of discussion on SonarQube Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/9gg_33IPo7E/f1T2EQ0CCQAJ